# How to support multi-resolution only with high resolution images

Tags: android

My Folder of drawable contains drawable-ldpi\drawable-mdpi\drawable-hdpi\drawable-xhdpi\drawable-xxhdpi to match the device whose resolution is 480x320\800x480\960x640\1280x720\1920x1080.I put a series of images into the folder of drawable-xxhdpi now,and the arrangement looks good in the testing machine with the same high resolution.
My question is how to support multi-resolution phone using the high resolution images.Taking into account adding the picture resized to a smaller one to the appropriate folder will increase the size of application,are there any other methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this reference, http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html, specially section "Density independence".

Please consider the system scales drawable resources to the appropriate size, based on the current screen density, if necessary.
So, for example, if you provide a drawable resource for the highest resolution, you don't have to produce also different images for other densities, because the system will do that for you.

Comment: +1 for "because the system will do that for you". I came here to see if this thing holds which I heard from a colleague. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

You must customize image in your folder.You can source high image resolution but you must changend and  customize image.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reference to [multi device options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources).

You don't need to put resources in anything but `res/ layout/` or `drawable/` but if you want your program to have a better experience on multiple devices with different `screens / density / languages` you may want to consider that you have that option.